# Façade keeps crashing, website trouble shooting doesn't seem to work

Tags: technical-issues, facade

I've tried everything to get Façade to run but it keeps crashing with the following message:

> We're sorry, Façade is having trouble running, possibly because other applications are running, it some other factor limiting the CPU available. Please try running Façade again, after closing other applications or restarting.

Here are the things I've tried when troubleshooting:

- having the game be the only program running
- running the game in admin mode
- double-checking system requirements (I'm using a GTX 1060 with a Ryzen 5 1400 and 8 GB of memory)
- setting the program as the top priority
- a fresh install using a different download site (using the 1.1b patch)
- running the game in windows xp/7 compatibility mode
- setting anti-aliasing and anti-isotropic to application controlled

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:

I want to note that I've never been able to get the game to work on this PC

Things I've tried doing since the initial post:

- disabling the fullscreen optimization (still crashes with the same error message)

Comment: Has it ever worked on your computer or is this your first time running it?

Comment: Try to disable fullscreen optimization. Right-click the game's .EXE file, Properties → Compatibility tab → tick 'Disable fullscreen optimizations'.

Comment: Try installing and running the game in a directory other than Program Files. E.g., under `C:\Games\`. Some old games don't like being installed in the Program Files directory due to restrictions made by newer versions of Windows.  When you install the game, run the installer as an admin.

Comment: The game is installed on a separate hard drive. I'll try installing it in my C drive to see if it works there

Comment: @Chuffedchips Here are some more troubleshooting stuff I could think of: Try [limiting Facade to use a single CPU core.](https://superuser.com/a/309663/10259). Try disabling DEP. If it still doesn't work, it might be an incompatibility with your hardware, drivers, and/or the OS. You might need to use a Virtual Machine, e.g., Virtual Box to run Windows XP on Windows 10. (Facade is a Windows XP-era game).

Comment: @galacticninja I've tried your first two suggestions (limiting core usage and disabling DEP) still getting the error message. I can't operate a Virtual Machine on my computer since it doesn't allow for virtual visualization. I've dug out an old windows 7 desktop and am trying to get facade to run on that.